# Close other tabs chrome using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

I am developing an intranet web application and the requirement is such that only one url should be opened at a time in chrome.
Currently the url is opened by a third party windows application on which we don't have any control!
Is there any way I can achieve that?
Summary is when the third party windows application opens the url (specified by me) all the other chrome tabs should close expect the current one.

Comment: On the UX side: If I would encounter this on your site this would be the last time I visited it. On the technical side: not possible

Comment: Imagine any website could close all other tabs. Would that be a good idea? Perhaps you can do something with an extension or userscript, but luckily it's impossible out of the box. And what should happen if the user opens a new tab _after_ opening your site?

Comment: Please read my comment carefully @Ramunas, I have clearly mentioned **bold**intranet..I guess you know what intranet means!

Comment: Please read my comment carefully @CodeCaster .. I have clearly mentioned **bold**intranet..I guess you know what intranet means!

Comment: Do you want to get help, or are you here to make snappy comments? Like I tried to explain, browsers do not offer this capability because it could easily be abused. A browser usually doesn't care whether it's visiting an intranet or internet page.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I didn't know UX has different rules for intranet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got my answer which was answered in another post in [Chrome Extension to Loop to Close Non-Selected Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391647/chrome-extension-to-loop-to-close-non-selected-tabs).
This solved my problem. All I had to do was close any window other than the current window. So at any point of time I will have only one chrome tab active.This solved my problem. Thanks for all your suggestions and comments. I am really sorry if I had said something wrong! Special thanks to @Harpyon ..

Answer (score 0):

Asuming all tabs are sharing the same domain, you can use JS localStorage with events on page load:

```
function storageChange(event) {
    if(event.key == 'open') {
        window.close();
        //todo: except current window
    }
}
window.addEventListener('storage', storageChange, false);
window.localStorage.setItem('open', true);
```

This will close all tabs with the same page loaded.
You should just detect the current one and keep it open

Comment: I am not good with javascripts so could please help me with a clear functional example? Let us assume that I have a [link]http://test.com and when ever this page loads what should I do? What is the script I should I use and where?

Comment: The script should be inside all page opened, you can't close tabs from outside. Wrap the code inside <script>window.onload= function(){ ... code...}</script> and put it in every page.